# How to check the preview mode

Tags: presentation

I have a page whose menu bar loads fine when previewed by clicking *Presentation > Preview*.

When previewed by clicking *Publish > Preview*, the site's menu bar is overlapped by Sitecore menu.

To fix that, I want to add a `margin-top` css property for the menu bar when it is being previewed using *Publish > Preview*.

How can I do that, as for both the methods, the page mode is `Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview`

Answer (score 2):

Presentation-preview is designed for Content Editor Users, Publish-preview - for Page Editor users. 
This is the main concept difference, in my opinion. Technically they use different engines: the presentation-preview uses the one inherited from old 5.3/6.0-6.3 versions, and the publish-preview uses Page Editor Engine invented in 6.4 versions.

Publish -> Preview also provides other options such as allowing you to choose the device while previewing.
On the other hand, Presentation -> Preview uses the first device that has "Default" field checked under the /sitecore/layout/devices item

So my suggestion is to forget to use Presententation -> Preview , recommended practice in Sitecore is to use Experience Editor not Content Editor for editing pages.

Answer (score 1):

Presentation Tab Preview runs in the context of your "website" site & Preview from Publish runs based on your site definition & hostname entry. Also you can check the URL triggered while accessing like below:

Presentation Tab: http://?**sc_site=website**&sc_lang&sc_mode=preview
Publish Tab:  http://?sc_itemid=&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=

Answer (score 0):

The `Request.Url` looks like below if you are in presentation->preview

> http://hostname/en?uri=sitecore://master/{ID}?lang=en-GB&ver=8&sc_site=website&sc_lang=en-GB&sc_mode=preview&sc_duration=temporary&sc_device={ID}

The `Request.Url` looks like below if you are in publish->preview

> http://hostname/?sc_itemid={ID}&sc_mode=preview&sc_lang=en-GB&sc_site=website

the main difference i spot is

> uri=sitecore

based on that we can find whether we are in presentation preview or publish preview

```
var previewtype = Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsPreview ? Request.Url.PathAndQuery.Contains("uri=sitecore") ? "presentation-preview" : "publish-preview" : "not-previewMode";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether the page is in Preview mode inside the navigation component and add z-index or margin depending on your solution.